# using GnuWin32 make getting error : make: *** No rule to make target `g++.exe', needed by `server.o'. Stop

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

My OS is windows8.1 x64
Not sure what i'm missing here the sever.cpp exist and if i run this cmd :
"g++.exe -c server.cpp -o server.o" it works ... i'm running all cmds from git-bash window

This is a simple Makefile:

```
# Specify compiler
CC=g++.exe

# Specify linker
LINK=g++.exe

# Build all target
.PHONY : all
all : app

# Link the object files and dependent libraries into a binary
app : server.o  \
    $(LINK) -o server server.o -lstdc++

# Compile the source files into object files
server.o : server.cpp   \
    $(CC) -c server.cpp -o server.o
```

Answer (score 0):

In a makefile, the backslash character acts as an escape, which allows you to split a single line of makefile over multiple physical lines in the file. Thus, your makefile is equivalent to:

```
# Specify compiler
CC=g++.exe

# Specify linker
LINK=g++.exe

# Build all target
.PHONY : all
all : app

# Link the object files and dependent libraries into a binary
app : server.o $(LINK) -o server server.o -lstdc++

# Compile the source files into object files
server.o : server.cpp $(CC) -c server.cpp -o server.o
```

or with variables resolved:

```
# Link the object files and dependent libraries into a binary
app : server.o g++.exe -o server server.o -lstdc++

# Compile the source files into object files
server.o : server.cpp g++.exe -c server.cpp -o server.o
```

This declares a target `app` with dependencies `server.o`, `g++.exe`, `-o`, `server`, `server.o`, and `-lstdc++`, all of  which will be searched for in the current directory. Moreover, the target doesn't include any steps.

To resolve this, remove the backslashes, and only use them when you want to break a line for readability/convenience without having it actually parse as a line break:

```
# Link the object files and dependent libraries into a binary
app : server.o 
    $(LINK) -o server server.o -lstdc++

# Compile the source files into object files
server.o : server.cpp 
    $(CC) -c server.cpp -o server.o
```

Comment: Right, i removed the backslashes , but still getting an error for: 
make: *** No rule to make target `g++.exe', needed by `server.o'.  Stop.
So, this is it can't find g++.exe , right ? 
so the g++.exe is in the "path" and if i run g++ --version from the the same git bash it's ok:
$g++.exe --version
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Why Makefile cant access "path" to look for g++.exe?

Comment: @Dby I cannot reproduce your issue. If there are newlines and suitable tabs on the next line per Makefile syntax, my copy of `make` handles your makefile without trouble. Did you make sure to remove the backslashes while leaving the newline and the tab on the next line in?